# Geocode Earth Autocomplete Box Without Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, react-leaflet, geocode

I am trying to integrate geocode.earth autcomplete search API without a map similar to the example on their site. [image]

I am a python and scala developer but I am new to front end and I was trying to figure out what was used for the autocomplete without the map. A detailed leaflet example (Map + Autcomplete) is provided but not the autocomplete by itself.

I tried integrating this example but it doesnt work properly.

````
import GeocodeEarthAutocomplete from 'react-geocode-earth-autocomplete';

export default (props) => {
    const [address, setAddress] = useState();

    return (
      <GeocodeEarthAutocomplete
        searchOptions={{
          api_key: "ge-..."
        }}
        value={address}
        onChange={(newAddress) => {
          setAddress(newAddress);
        }}
        onSelect={(newAddress) => {
          // do an api call
        }}
      >
        {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => {
          <div>
            <input
              {...getInputProps({
                placeholder: 'Search Places ...',
                className: 'location-search-input',
              })}
            />
            <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
              {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
              {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                const className = suggestion.active
                  ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                  : 'suggestion-item';
                // inline style for demonstration purpose
                const style = suggestion.active
                  ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                  : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                return (
                  <div
                    {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                      className,
                      style,
                    })}
                  >
                    <span>{suggestion.description}</span>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </GeocodeEarthAutocomplete>
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Esri's ArcGIS rest api.  What you're looking for is the [geocoding-suggest](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-suggest.htm) endpoint, which returns a JSON of possible locations for a partially typed search term.  For example, the endpoint:

```js
https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/suggest?text=san%20&maxSuggestions=5&f=json
```

Returns some values like this:

```json
[
  {
    "text": "San Bartolomé",
    "magicKey": "dHA9MCNsb2M9Mjg3MjI5MzYjbG5nPTE0MCNwbD0xNzc4MzI5NCNsYnM9MTQ6MzIzNTA1MzI=",
    "isCollection": false
  },
  {
    "text": "San Kitts y Nevis",
    "magicKey": "dHA9MCNsb2M9NDA3ODE0MTcjbG5nPTE0MCNwbD00MzA2ODYyOSNsYnM9MTQ6MzIzNjU5Njc=",
    "isCollection": false
  },
  {
    "text": "San Marino",
    "magicKey": "dHA9MCNsb2M9NDgwNTc0NzcjbG5nPTY1I3BsPTUxMDgxMjYzI2xicz0xNDozMjM2ODQxMQ==",
    "isCollection": false
  },
  {
    "text": "San Martenas",
    "magicKey": "dHA9MCNsb2M9NDg4ODY2MDAjbG5nPTg0I3BsPTUxNjQ1ODYwI2xicz0xNDozMjM2ODU3MA==",
    "isCollection": false
  },
  {
    "text": "San Martin",
    "magicKey": "dHA9MCNsb2M9NDEyMzg3ODgjbG5nPTY1I3BsPTQzNjU5ODU4I2xicz0xNDozMjM2ODU3Mg==",
    "isCollection": false
  }
]
```

So you can hook a text input up to this endpoint to read what the user is typing and offer some autocompletion, no map necessary.  There's lots of params you can use to customize it too.

Answer (score 0):

Co-founder of Geocode Earth here.

We've recently released our [Autocomplete Element](https://geocode.earth/docs/components/autocomplete-element/), a lightweight, React-based [Web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) that lets you easily add a search box to any web page, with or without a map.

The full setup instructions can be found in our docs listed above, but something like this will work for most people:

```html
<!-- load the autocomplete element code. An NPM module is also available if you prefer -->
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@geocodeearth/autocomplete-element/dist/bundle.js"></script>

<!-- add the autocomplete element wherever you'd like on your page -->
<ge-autocomplete api_key="YOUR-API-KEY"></ge-autocomplete>
```

The Autocomplete Element incorporates all our hard-learned best practices for autocomplete interfaces (it's harder than you'd think to get right!) and is [open source](https://github.com/geocodeearth/autocomplete-element) so that it's easy to inspect, improve, and build upon.